# Want to change a correct UIButton image from UITableViewCell on click same UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

i have UIButton in UITableViewCell. multiple UIButtons image are changing when i click UIButton in UITableViewCell. suppose, there are 10 UIButton showing because of Json Data. next i will click on UIButton in UITableViewCell. as a result have been change image in UIButton 1,3,5,7,9. but it should be changed one UIButton image. please help me i post codes.i just want to change a specific UIButton image from UITableViewCell on click UIButton

**TableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

    let arrNewsList = [[Home]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.homeTableView.delegate = self
        self.homeTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrNewsList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrNewsList[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell2
        return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return self.view.frame.size.height

}
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
class HomeTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bookMarkBtn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    @IBAction func bookMarkBtnClick(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let btnCheck = sender as? UIButton else {
            return
        }

        btnCheck.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_blue"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: have you created any Model class object  for your json response? can youn share your sample json?

Comment: Its a problem caused as dequeue reusable cell memory, is reflecting that.

Comment: @NilomiShah try to help me

Comment: in your custom cell, try adding `prepareForReuse()` and setting the button variable to nil

Comment: @RachelHarvey  `override func prepareForReuse() {
   
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
     bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_white"), for: UIControlState.normal)
     bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_blue"), for: UIControlState.selected)
    }` i used to this code still not work

Comment: @EmmaAni - what about sharad answer

Comment: @Anbu.karthik when i select button in uiTableViewCell. there are change multiple button's image in tableViewController

Comment: @Anbu.karthik  i just want to change image on button. which button i will click

Comment: @EmmaAni - i got it bro, plz update your ? based on sharad answer

Comment: @Anbu.karthik i do not understand sorry.

Comment: @EmmaAni - can you update your question followed by sharad chahaun answer

Comment: @Anbu.karthik i used to `sharad chahaun` codes it is not working properly. suppose, i made 10 button by a array. when i click button one then image has changed on 1 and 9 no button, sometimes 1 and 10 button.

Comment: @NilomiShah i already said

Comment: @NilomiShah suppose, i made 10 button by a array. when i click button one then image has changed on 1 and 9 no button, sometimes 1 and 10 button. if happened after use your code

Comment: my problem still not solve please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a Problem as your TableView Cell button is reusing memory.

I had faced such Problem once, You can do is maintain an array.

Take same number of elements as that in your array which is used to display items in table

For example  :

```
var arrayButton = [Int]
    for elements in mainArray {
       arrayButton.append(0)
    }
```

Now Your array is ready,

Change its Value when button state is changed ,
 0 = Disabled
1 : selected

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell2
  cell.bookMarkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bookMarkBtnClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    if(arrayButton[indexPath.row] == 1) {
          cell.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "set_selected_image"), for: UIControlState.normal)
       }
     else {
         cell.bookMarkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "set_unselected_image"), for: UIControlState.normal)
     }
     cell.bookMarkBtn.tag = indexPath.row
     return cell
  }




  func bookMarkBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
        if(arrayButton[sender.tag] == 1){
            arrayButton[sender.tag] = 0
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "set_unselected_image"), for: UIControlState.normal)
         }
          else {
               arrayButton[sender.tag] = 1 
               sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "set_selected_image"), for: UIControlState.normal)
}
}
```

Comment: `@objc func bookMarkBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
        if(arrayButton[sender.tag] == 1){
            
      **i got error down line**
            // Use of unresolved identifier 'intIndexPath'
           arrayButton[intIndexPath] = 0
        }
        else {
            arrayButton[sender.tag] = 1
        }
}`

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier intIndexPath `arrayButton[intIndexPath] = 0`

Comment: SEE NOW @EmmaAni

Comment: I forgot to change that sorry, check now

Comment: friend! button's image is not changing

Comment: Friend! it show `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` when i used 2d array

Comment: Friend! it works very well when i use 1d array. it is not working when i used 2d array please help me.  `if(arrayButton[indexPath.row] == 1) {`  `Fatal error: Index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking button action in your cell class take an outlet. And in cellForRowAt add action to it.

Something like this :

```
class HomeTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bookMarkBtn: UIButton!

     override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()

     }
 }
```

And in cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell2

    cell.bookMarkBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.bookMarkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bookMarkBtnClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Make this fucntion in your ViewController only :

```
func bookMarkBtnClick(sender: UIButton) {
   sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "favorite_blue"), for: UIControlState.normal)

}
```

Comment: sorry i am not realize

Comment: please try to add some code with your answer thank you

Comment: Can you show what you have done ? Coz same thing is working for me ? If you click on a button that button's image should change right ?

Comment: problem is like previous

Comment: have been change image in UIButton 1,3,5,7,9. again when i click button 2. image come to change in 2,4,6,8,10

Comment: @EmmaAni can you share your code on email or github link ?

Comment: Problem is of Deque reusable cell, as it uses the same memory. So it reflects that.

Comment: `let arrNewsList = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]` add this array in project and can it selected multiple button. when you click 1 or 2. then 10 will be automatic selected

Comment: @EmmaAni It's not clear what you want. You want one button at a time to be selected or you want multiple button's to be selected ?

Comment: @sharadchauhan You want one button at a time to be selected

Comment: Then use @NilomiShah's idea, that's one option.

Comment: @sharadchauhan hello friend please help me @NilomiShah' is not working yet.  got error down line is `Use of unresolved identifier 'intIndexPath'` in `arrayButton[intIndexPath] = 0`

Comment: @NilomiShah i used you i got array `Use of unresolved identifier 'intIndexPath' in arrayButton[intIndexPath] = 0`